# Host OpenVPN Server on Android Device

Tags: linux, android, openvpn

I have a running and fully functional OpenVPN server running on a PC ( sometimes on Windows and Sometimes on Linux(Ubuntu) ).

I Want to know if there is a way to host the server on and Android Powered Device like a tablet for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it **only** if you root your device, which, by definition, is something you will not find on the Android App Store. Yet it can be done without running any risk, even though it is a bit complex.

You can find [here](http://davebennett.tech/vpn-server-android/) extensive instructions, with a link to further instructions on how to root your device, and install Linux as an app inside Android. It is fun, but it is a lot of work. Not sure setting up an OpenVPN *server* on a tablet alone justifies this much work. But hey, YMMV...

Comment: There are many apps that require root on the Play Store.

Comment: @DanielB You are equivocating: what I am saying is that he will find no info on the PlayStore on how to root nor will he find the relevant software. I do not mean there is nothing that requires rooting in the PlayStre.

Answer (score 0):

You want to connect an Android device to an OpenVPN server or you want the Android device itself to be the server?

If you're asking for the former, then you install the [OpenVPN Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.openvpn.openvpn&hl=en) client on Android.

If you're asking for the latter, then I don't think there is an OpenVPN server available for Android. That is, not in the official Google Play store. I don't ever recommend side-loading tools from unofficial sources. I especially recommend against side-loading security software.